# Iniciar serviço através da ação do usuário

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Bom dia! 
Tenho um aplicativo que irá receber PushNotification. 
Mas o usuário poderá selecionar se quer ou não receber as notificações.

Tenho um `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`  e um `IntentService` que verificam se há mensagem. 
 Estes, iniciam automaticamente, com a aplicação. 
Gostaria de saber há possibilidade de iniciar este serviço apenas quando o usuário selecionar a opção. e não quando iniciar o aplicativo? 
Declaração no **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".services.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="br.com.app.auto.application.AutoApplication" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".services.NotificationService" />
```

Desde já agradeço a colaboração! 
 Saudações!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar registrar um receiver via código no seu aplicativo, mas não encontrei nenhum exemplo disso e provavelmente não irá funcionar. Os exemplos de GCM todos registram o *receiver* no Android Manifest.xml.

[Esta resposta do SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322516/dynamic-register-of-c2dm-receiver-using-registerreceiver) diz que é preciso ser assim porque a *push notification* deve ser capaz de "acordar" (iniciar) o aplicativo caso ele não esteja em execução no momento. Se o *receiver* fosse registrado for via código, a *push notification* se perderia caso o aplicativo não estivesse em execução quando ela chegasse. A resposta se refere ao C2DM, que é a versão anterior do GCM, mas provavelmente no GCM continua sendo assim pela mesma razão.

Também não é recomendado ficar registrando e "desregistrando" o Registration ID para controlar o envio dos *pushes*, segundo diz a documentação. Esse ID deve ser recebido uma vez, ser armazenado no aplicativo e ficar em uso até o aplicativo ser desinstalado pelo usuário.

O jeito então é você manter um campo extra na sua tabela de dispositivos registrados no servidor (ou na sua tabela de usuários, ou de configurações de usuário, enfim, você decide) indicando se o usuário deseja receber ou não as *push notifications*, e disponibilizar *web services* para alterar essa configuração via aplicativo. Essa abordagem pode ser usada para controlar a preferência do usuário e também para permitir que ele só receba *pushes* estando logado no aplicativo.

Comment: OK! Pensei em parar o serviço, pois se o usuário não deseja receber as notificações, não há a necessidade de executar o Serviço. O controle via servidor também será feito, para evitar processamento desnecessário! Muito Obrigado pelo auxílio!

Answer (score 0):

Retire este action da tag

```
    <receiver android:name=".NOMEDORECEIVER">
                <intent-filter>
este ---->       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

Assim ele não irá inciar no boot do android

Comment: Removi, mas quando inicio o Serviço ( getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), GcmBroadcastReceiver.class)); ) ele não funciona!

Comment: Me desculpe, acho que errei na explicação, vou editar.

Comment: Então... nem tem essa linha não!

Comment: Coloca seu código na pergunta por favor, talvez seja mais fácil encontrar o problema

Comment: Na verdade não tenho o código! é exatamente esta a dúvida... como fazer? Obrigado!